# Firefox reclama de código após o return

Tags: javascript, return

#### Situação

Estava realizando a manutenção de algumas funções no JS.
E um determinada função coloquei um `return` no meio dela, pois o restante não era mais necessário.
Em ver do comentar o restante ou apagar, mantive o código ali.
Ao recarregar a pagina o console dispara esta mensagem:

> SyntaxError: unreachable code after return statement
>
> Erro de sintaxe : código inacessível após a instrução de retorno

#### Codigo

```
function ajustaTela(){
    jQuery('.data').datepick();
    return;

    if(jQuery(document).innerWidth() < 1050){
        jQuery("#panel-header #panel-header-content #menu_header li").css({'padding':'6px 5px'});
    }else{
        jQuery("#panel-header #panel-header-content #menu_header li").css({'padding':'6px 10px'});
    }
    
    jQuery('span.adicionar_favoritos').css('margin-left', ((jQuery('span.adicionar_favoritos').parents('div.panel_title').width() / 2)-15) + 'px');
    
    jQuery('.data').datepick();
    
    makeHeaderFixedSize();
}
```

#### Duvida

Quais possíveis problemas eu posso ter em manter um código apos o `return`?

#### Obs

Navegador : firefox 40.0

Comment: Tem como postar o código aqui?

Comment: Ao meu ver, não há problemas em manter códigos após o return se ele fizer parte da lógica, agora manter código não utilizado pode ser um problema grande, imagine se algo inesperado acontece e não executa o return, o código irá executar o trecho não utilizado podendo causar problemas.

Comment: Qual navegador usou? usou alguma diretiva mais rigorosa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O erro de sintaxe já quebra o código e isso é um problema. Esse erro quer dizer "*Olha, aqui tem código morto (nunca será executado) depois do `return`. Remova ele antes que alguém ache que ele serve para alguma coisa*".

O ideal é remover o código morto no lugar de comentá-lo pois algum outro programador pode querer testar ele.

Comment: Curioso, a MDN diz que é um Warning, não um Error.

Comment: @bfavaretto tem o link? manda ai ... será que varia de navegador?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Comment: Então, aparentemente este warning `unreachable code after return statement` começou no gecko 40, pelo menos é oque diz no mdn, desta forma o webkit não possui este warning correto ?

Answer (score 2):

desculpa a afirmação porque não entendi muito bem o seu motivo de deixar o código, mas o erro é deixar algo depois do return, o qual não será usado nunca, isso independente de linguagem.

Duas sugestões e você me permite:

1) comenta o código todo após o return e deixe uma explicação do porque;
2) ou apague o código todo após o return.

[Nesse link fala de uma linguagem compilada e porque remover, o JavaScript é linguagem interpretada, mas dá uma boa explicação porque remover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination)

Comment: Eu sempre comento, apenas foi um duvida de ambiente de teste : D